# Conflicting routes in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an annoying problem with routes in asp.net mvc. I've created a custom route handler to handle XMLRPC calls to my site and I want to route this to /xmlrpc/pingback.

In global.asax.cs I have this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

routes.Add(new Route("xmlrpc/pingback", null,
            new RouteValueDictionary(),
            new PingbackRouteHandler()));
```

Now the xmlrpc/pingback isn't found, because there is no controller called xmlrpc.

If I switch the order to the xmlrpc routes comes first the xmlrpc works, but every other /controller/action routes is mapped to /xmlrpc/pingback?controller=home&action=index.

How can I create a constraint that matches every controller name except "xmlrpc"? Or is there another way of doing this?

// Joan

Comment: Why don't you just use an MVC controller instead of a custom handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `controller = "Fake"` to the Pingback route's defaults to prevent it from matching other routes.